# Axios not capturing stream error properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I have some codes to fetch ndjson data using axios and I have the following codes. The api will constantly return a stream of data throughout the day. The data will then be sent to all the clients via socketio.

My problem is, after running for a couple of hours, the stream stops/fails silently ( i know because it stops sending data to the clients via socket ).

**I would like to know how can I capture the error and restart the process. Current codes are not doing it properly.**

```
const getData = () => {
try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream'})
    
    
    const stream = response.data
    
    stream.on('data', (data) => {
        processData(data)
    })
    
    stream.on('end', () => {
        console.log("stream end") //<-- didn't print
        getData() //<-- didn't call
    })
} catch(err) {
console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: that code will never run, since it's not an `async` function, `await` will throw an error - furthermore, don't use `.then/.catch` with `async/await` ... use `try/catch` if you're using `async/await` and want to handle promise rejections

Comment: Thanks actually in original code was try catch, ive edited the code. it was a mistake.

Comment: `stream.on('error', err=>{ do something when there's an error })`?